# OpenGL ES, getting a simple dot to move with onDrawFrame

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am just playing around with a Pong clone for my android phone. I can get this image up on screen with the code I have so far:

[image]

For some reason the code below doesn't cause the ball/dot to move around the screen.

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    // Clear the rendering surface.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    table.draw(shaderProgram);

    paddle.bindData(shaderProgram);
    paddle.draw(shaderProgram);


    ball.bindData(shaderProgram);
    ball.draw(shaderProgram);
    ball.translate(0.1f);
}
```

I know it is better to use a model matrix to move things but I'm just playing around before I refine it. Anyway, here is the ball.translate method()

```
public void translate(float amount)
{
    for(int i=0; i<VERTEX_DATA.length; i++)
    {
        VERTEX_DATA[i] += amount;
    }
}
```

- From my understanding, onDrawFrame() gets called at every frame change
- The ball object contains vertex data
- ball.bindData() puts the vertex data into native memory and links it to the attributes in the shaders.
- ball.translate() updates the vertex data within the ball object and then everything is binded again to the shader and redrawn.

Comment: Is your render mode set to RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY? It should be RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUS (which is the default and what you want) but worth a quick check...

Comment: I have never heard of this render mode so maybe that is what it is. I'll have a look and get back to you. Ta!

Comment: You use WHEN_DIRTY if your screen doesn't need updating continuously (for example if you only want to redraw when the user swipes the screen). The default is continous though so if you haven't changed or set the render mode in your code it's not the cause.

Comment: Oh yes I understand now. I looked in my code to see if it was set to WHEN_DIRTY (because part of the code is lifted from tutorials). It looks like renderMode is still at default settings.

Comment: Oh I realized where I went wrong. I forgot to add an assignment. After updating the vertex data and before binding the data, I was meant to add this: 'vertexArray = new VertexArray(VERTEX_DATA);'. Thanks for all your help NigelK I appreciate it.